# Forward Voltage drop of laser line module

Tags: voltage, diodes, laser

I have a laser line module with the following specifications:

`Operating Voltage: 2.6-5 V
Operating Current: <35mA
Output Power: <1mw`

No where in the data sheet does it mention anything about a forward drop voltage (I am assuming this is a diode).
Is it safe to assume the forward voltage drop is 2.6V?

Product: Quarton Laser Module VLM-650-28 LPT Red Laser Line Generator

Comment: Laser Vforward changes drastically with temperature.

Answer (score 1):

This module almost certainly contains the laser controller as well as the diode.  From the little information you give it implies that the operating voltage is between 2.6 and 5V.  The actual laser diode itself may have about 1.8V drop if it is red more if green less if infra red.

When asking questions like this you should give the part number and any other information you have, picture, data sheet etc - think of how you are asking others to answer a question with very little context. You should always try searching for a data sheet before enquiring here.  Just Google it!

Edit - Now you have given us the part number I can see some of the description and it includes the Laser driver - so the external voltage is not that of the laser itself:

Digikey has a data sheet of the 650-27 (not 28) with more information.  The voltage range is between 2.6 and 5V.

Comment: My apologies, I completely forgot to paste it in. I have added the name of the laser including the model and type. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

It's not *just* a diode. There's at least a constant-current circuit in there.

Feed it a constant voltage somewhere within the operating range, such as 3.3V.

Incidentally, the line vs. spot is an optical difference- the driving circuit does not have to change.